# Front end form tag field for wordpress

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, forms, tags

I have a need to set up a tag selector on front end form to be filled by the user of my website, I want to reuse the type of functionality that the wordpress provides for the administrator when selecting tags for new topics (see image below).

There is a separate panel for this tag selection with auto-complete functionality along with most popular tags list. How can I bring the whole panel on a front end form page for my user of website ? Are there plugins like simple tags related to this kind of functionality ?

How can I achieve this ? I have no clue, can some one help me by pointing in the right direction ?

[image: Back end tag selector]

Comment: http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-custom-wordpress-widget/